# Put a class on every list item in the third row with jQuery filtering

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-filter

I have a media gallery. For some weird reason, the designer decided to put these media items in blocks of 12. Three rows, four items per row and then a gap.

Now I do not feel like putting a list of 12 items in a parent list per block.
I thought this could easily be handled by jQuery filtering, adding a class on every 
item of every third row.

I know how to target every `:nth(4)` item, every fourth item in the list, but how do I do every item in the third row?

What filter can I use for something like that?

The markup is listed below. All items are just floating elements in a unordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
</ul>
```

Floating, and four items fit per row.
So I would need to target item 9, 10, 11 and 12, but also three rows further, item 21, 22, 23, 24 and again...

I thought I could do it with some nifty calculation in the `.filter(function(){});`, but I'm not even close to the correct answer yet...

What I want to have is actually visible in this jsfiddle I just made: http://jsfiddle.net/DpMRc/5/**

I want to target the blue boxes with a `.filter()` function instead of having to write the whole `for` loop for it.

Comment: Are the rows actually in the markup, or are they just laid out that way?  Basically, it would be helpful in writing selectors for your markup if your were more explicit about what your markup is.

Comment: sorry to have mislead anyone with this answer, most people went with the thought that i use tables (talking about rows and all)
though it's really just an unordered list with floating elements where i need a certain amount of elements filtered out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using jQuery because you want IE8 support, but in all other browsers (including IE9), you can do this with just CSS:

```
li:nth-child(12n+9), li:nth-child(12n+10), li:nth-child(12n+11), li:nth-child(12n+12) {
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/tXLLn/), I've made a guess as to what a simplified version of the rest of your CSS would look like.  The same selectors will work in jQuery if you want to polyfill for IE, but I would suggest you do that in conditional comments so as to not waste time on other browsers.

Comment: well, it does provide me the solution
i will however be using the jquery equivalent as the impact seems rather minimal, The use of conditional styles is almost impossible in this situation

this is already ajax loaded content, so implementing a IE8 only script to format this list would be tricky.

thanks a lot for the help! i'll keep my eyes open and test around to see the real performance impact... !

Answer (score 2):

One option is:

```
$('tbody tr').filter(
    function(i){
        if ((i+1)%3 == 0){
            return this;
        }
    }).addClass('black');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WE8qG/2/).

And then use the class of the `tr` element to style the children in some manner:

```
.black td {
    /* css for the td elements that are children of the tr with the class of 'black' */
}
```

Or you could use:

```
$('tbody tr').filter(
    function(i){
        if ((i+1)%3 == 0){
            return this;
        }
    }).children().addClass('black');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WE8qG/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *  in the selector? Or particular tag?

```
$('table tr:nth-child(3) > *')....
```

or

```
$('table tr:nth-child(3) > td')...
```

depends on whether you wan't to address direct child or all descendants, in that case remove the `>` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq(). for example

```
$('table tr:eq(3) td:nth-child(6)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')
});
```

selects the 6th 'td' of the third row. You can combine that with some logic to calculate the index for eq to choose every third row

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2Ru3/

Comment: sorry to have mislead you with the structure, i had to be more obvious so now i'm showing what i really use, is just an unordered list, so i cannot loop over rows as in actual elements :s